# Eclipse settings corrupted. How do I change to default?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After trying to add a C++ compiler, eclipse was corrupted. I reinstalled but now it's still giving me errors when trying to rebuild android.

how do i completely reset the settings?  This is from the log.

The following report will be sent to Eclipse:

---

### STATUS

```
pluginId            org.eclipse.ui.navigator
pluginVersion       3.6.0.v20150422-0725
code                2
severity            4
message             Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.navigator".
fingerprint         1daa4d93348d296d323ab749313725e6

Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: null
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:153)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:500)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:237)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:437)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:419)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:413)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:406)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeSourceRoots(CProject.java:584)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeChildren(CProject.java:605)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.buildStructure(CProject.java:569)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:261)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.openWhenClosed(CElement.java:427)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:305)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:295)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Parent.getChildren(Parent.java:55)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:290)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:267)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel.create(CoreModel.java:146)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.BaseCElementContentProvider.internalGetParent(BaseCElementContentProvider.java:335)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.cview.CViewContentProvider.internalGetParent(CViewContentProvider.java:193)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.BaseCElementContentProvider.getParent(BaseCElementContentProvider.java:328)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.navigator.CNavigatorContentProvider.getParent(CNavigatorContentProvider.java:193)
     at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.navigator.CNavigatorContentProvider.getPipelinedParent(CNavigatorContentProvider.java:319)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.getPipelinedParent(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:189)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findParent(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:679)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.access$8(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:667)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$4.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:648)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findParents(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:623)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.findPaths(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:594)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getParents(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:330)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getParentElement(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1697)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getParentElement(TreeViewer.java:573)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRemove(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1961)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$6.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2218)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1462)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:366)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1423)
     at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.remove(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2215)
     at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.remove(CommonViewer.java:322)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider$2.run(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:257)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider.runUpdates(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:293)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider.access$1(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:291)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider$1.run(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:115)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4024)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
     at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:172)
     at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:387)
     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:500)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.run(ProgressMonitorJobsDialog.java:284)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$3.run(ProgressManager.java:997)
     at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:1032)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.busyCursorWhile(ProgressManager.java:1007)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:799)
     at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:429)
     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
     at HIDDEN.HIDDEN(HIDDEN:-1)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
     at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
     at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

---

### REPORT

```
anonymousId         12641ecc-7f2d-4906-8655-124655820028
name                amir meshkin
email               amir.meshkin@gmail.com
comment             
eclipseBuildId      4.5.2.M20160212-1500
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_60-b27
osgiWs              cocoa
osgiOs              MacOSX
osgiOsVersion       10.11.5
osgiArch            x86_64
severity            UNKNOWN
```

---

### BUNDLES

```
name                com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
version             23.0.7.2120684

name                org.eclipse.cdt.core
version             5.11.0.201602051005

name                org.eclipse.cdt
version             8.8.1.201602051005

name                org.eclipse.cdt.ui
version             5.11.0.201602051005

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.databinding
version             1.5.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.11.1.v20150903-1804

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
version             1.3.1.v20160203-0951

name                org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt
version             0.13.0.v20150504-0621

name                org.eclipse.equinox.app
version             1.3.300.v20150423-1356

name                org.eclipse.equinox.launcher
version             1.3.100.v20150511-1540

name                org.eclipse.jface
version             3.11.1.v20160128-1644

name                org.eclipse.swt
version             3.104.2.v20160212-1350

name                org.eclipse.ui
version             3.107.0.v20150507-1945

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide.application
version             1.1.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.ui.ide
version             3.11.0.v20150825-2158

name                org.eclipse.ui.navigator
version             3.6.0.v20150422-0725

name                org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources
version             3.5.1.v20160128-1644
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want eclipse to work again the easiest way i know is to delete all eclipse associated files and just use their installer which will install everything for you without problems.
[here is the link for the page where you select / see info about the installer](https://eclipse.org/downloads/index.php?show_instructions=TRUE)

to delete the files i used the search in the file explorer and than just deleted